# Calling a private method within a class in Perl 6

Tags: perl, raku

I can't call a private method within a class in Perl 6:

```
class MyClass {

  method !my-private-method($var1) {
    # ....
  }

  method my-method() {
    my $my-var1 = !my-private-method(123); # not found (Undeclared routines)
    my $my-var1 = $!my-private-method(123); # not found (Undeclared routines)
    my $my-var1 = $.my-private-method(123); # not found (Undeclared routines)
    my $my-var1 = my-private-method(123); # not found (Undeclared routines)
```

So how can I call `my-private-method` from `my-method`?

Comment: Are you sure about those variable and method names with the dashes in them?  It's sort of COBOL-like…

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, yes.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to call the private method on your instance object.

```
my $my-var1 = self!my-private-method(123);
```

should work.

Comment: out of curiosity, is there any way to call it without `self`?

Comment: @jawanam I'm not sure - still very much a perl6 newbie myself.

Comment: You can call it on the Class object. If you want a private subroutine, just write a subroutine in the class definition, as subs are lexical by default.